# VBA Replace error - string treated as formula

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am trying to clean some text contained in an very large Excel spreadsheet by replacing all instances "<br />" with a single space (" "). I've tried two methods: using the normal Find/Replace All options in Excel, and using this very simple VBA macro:

```
Sub CleanUp()
    Application.Cells.Replace What:="<br />", Replacement:=Chr(32), LookAt:=xlPart
End Sub
```

In both cases, I receive an error message that states: *"The formula you typed contains an error. For information about fixing common formula problems, click Help. To get assistance in entering a function, click Function Wizard (Formulas tab, Function Library group). If you are not trying to enter a formula, avoid using an equal sign (=) or minus sign (-), or precede it with a single quotation mark (')."*

Of course, I am NOT trying to enter a formula. However, preceding "<br />" with a single quotation mark as Excel suggests does not fix the problem.

Even though my search string doesn't contain any wildcards (as far as I know), I've tried playing around with literal characters in my macro to see if that would help. It doesn't fix the problem, but here's the code anyway:

```
Sub CleanUp()
  Dim SearchFor As String
  SearchFor = Chr$(60) & "br" & Chr$(32) & Chr$(47) & Chr$(62)
    Application.Cells.Replace What:=SearchFor, Replacement:=Chr$(32), LookAt:=xlPart
End Sub
```

Useful facts:

- I can easily find and replace other strings in this spreadsheet using both the normal find/replace method AND the VBA macro.
- I have other similar spreadsheets in which finding and replacing "<br />" is possible.
- On my friend's computer it is possible to find and replace all instances of "<br />" using both methods.

Does anyone have ANY idea why this is happening? Does it have something to do with my Excel settings?

Comment: Does it work if you try to do this on a single column (instead of all cells)?

Comment: I think you need to isolate the problematic string - presumably at some stage Excel is trying to update a formula which fails. I would delete half the data, run the test and then if the error happens again, keep on deleting and testing, or if the error doesn't happen restore the hald you deleted and then keep on halving and testing that

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! It does work on a single column. But there are no formulas in the spreadsheet at all, so I don't think the problem has to do with a failed updated formula...

Comment: Can you post your workbook on the net for us to test?

Comment: What if you format all the cells as Text and then perform the replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Cells.Replace What:="<br/>", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```